# Replacement for "GROUP BY" in ContentResolver query in Android Q ( Android 10, API 29 changes)

Tags: android-sqlite, android-contentresolver, mediastore, android-10.0

I'm upgrading some legacy to target Android Q, and of course this code stop working:

```
       String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            "COUNT(" + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + ") AS COUNT",
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID};

        String BUCKET_GROUP_BY = " 1) and " + BUCKET_WHERE.toString() + " GROUP BY 1,(2";

        cur = context.getContentResolver().query(images, PROJECTION_BUCKET,
            BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY);
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])

Here it supposed to obtain list of images with album name, date, count of pictures - one image for each album, so we can create album picker screen without querying all pictures and loop through it to create albums.

Is it possible to group query results with contentResolver since SQL queries stoped work?

(I know that ImageColumns.DATA and "COUNT() AS COUNT" are deprecated too, but this is a question about GROUP BY)

(There is a way to query albums and separately query photo, to obtain photo uri for album cover, but i want to avoid overheads)

Comment: Which overload of `query()` are you using. I can't find one that uses a GROUP BY argument: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver

Comment: @forpas this is no overload with group_by, i use

Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)

and send group_by String[] as selection

Comment: Hay, have you found solution to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately **Group By** is no longer supported in Android 10 and above, neither any aggregated functions such as **COUNT**. This is by design and there is no workaround.

The solution is what you are actually trying to avoid, which is to query, iterate, and get metrics.

To get you started you can use the next snipped, which will resolve the buckets (albums), and the amount of records in each one.

I haven't added code to resolve the thumbnails, but is easy. You must perform a query for each bucket Id from all the Album instances, and use the image from the first record.

```
public final class AlbumQuery
{
    @NonNull
    public static HashMap<String, AlbumQuery.Album> get(@NonNull final Context context)
    {
        final HashMap<String, AlbumQuery.Album> output     = new HashMap<>();
        final Uri                               contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};

        try (final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst() == true))
            {
                final int columnBucketName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int columnBucketId   = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID);

                do
                {
                    final String bucketId   = cursor.getString(columnBucketId);
                    final String bucketName = cursor.getString(columnBucketName);

                    if (output.containsKey(bucketId) == false)
                    {
                        final int              count = AlbumQuery.getCount(context, contentUri, bucketId);
                        final AlbumQuery.Album album = new AlbumQuery.Album(bucketId, bucketName, count);
                        output.put(bucketId, album);
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static int getCount(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Uri contentUri, @NonNull final String bucketId)
    {
        try (final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + "=?", new String[]{bucketId}, null))
        {
            return ((cursor == null) || (cursor.moveToFirst() == false)) ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
        }
    }

    public static final class Album
    {
        @NonNull
        public final String buckedId;
        @NonNull
        public final String bucketName;
        public final int    count;

        Album(@NonNull final String bucketId, @NonNull final String bucketName, final int count)
        {
            this.buckedId = bucketId;
            this.bucketName = bucketName;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer! But if i'll need to query every Image per every bucketId, it basically means that i will iterate through every Image on the device - this is those overheads that i've tried to avoid. Is it possible to query for only last image for every bucket id?

Comment: There is no other way as aggregate functions are not supported at all in Android 10. So, things such as selecting with "TOP n", will also not work anymore. Take into account that you are not iterating through each image in the device by itself, neither accessing or iterating files in the devices at all, instead you are iterating the rows in a cursor from the MediaStore, which is very fast even with a few thousand records

Answer (score 0):

**This is a more efficient(not perfect) way to do that.**

I am doing it for videos, but doing so is the same for images to. just change    MediaStore.Video.Media.X    to    MediaStore.Images.Media.X

```
public class QUtils {
        /*created by Nasib June 6, 2020*/
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        public static ArrayList<FolderHolder> loadListOfFolders(Context context) {
            ArrayList<FolderHolder> allFolders = new ArrayList<>();//list that we need
            HashMap<Long, String> folders = new HashMap<>();  //hashmap to track(no duplicates) folders by using their ids
    
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED};
    
            ContentResolver CR = context.getContentResolver();
    
            Uri root = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    
            Cursor c = CR.query(root, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
    
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                int folderIdIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID);
                int folderNameIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                int thumbIdIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                int dateAddedIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED);
    
                do {
                    Long folderId = c.getLong(folderIdIndex);

                    if (folders.containsKey(folderId) == false) { //proceed only if the folder data has not been inserted already :) 
                        long thumbId = c.getLong(thumbIdIndex);
                        String folderName = c.getString(folderNameIndex);
                        String dateAdded = c.getString(dateAddedIndex);
                        Uri thumbPath = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, thumbId);
                        folders.put(folderId, folderName);
                        allFolders.add(new FolderHolder(String.valueOf(thumbPath), folderName, dateAdded));
                    }

                } while (c.moveToNext());
    
                c.close(); //close cursor
                folders.clear(); //clear the hashmap becuase it's no more useful
            }
            return allFolders;
        }
    }
```

FolderHolder model class

```
public class FolderHolder {
    private String folderName;
    public long dateAdded;
    private String thumbnailPath;
    public long folderId;

    public void setPath(String thumbnailPath) {
        this.thumbnailPath = thumbnailPath;
    }

    public String getthumbnailPath() {
        return thumbnailPath;
    }

    public FolderHolder(long folderId, String thumbnailPath, String folderName, long dateAdded) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
        this.folderName = folderName;
        this.thumbnailPath = thumbnailPath;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }
    public String getFolderName() {
        return folderName;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give me a FolderHolder Object structure ?

Comment: @PrabodhaRanasinghe i have updated my answer and added folderholder model class.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_BY` supporting in case of using Bundle:

```
  val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString(
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SORT_ORDER,
                "${MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED} DESC"
            )
            putString(
                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID
            )
        }
        contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
            ),
            bundle,
            null
        )
```

Comment: Hey Alex. Can you please confirm is ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY working in android 10. I tried this with android pie; it is not supported and lint says it is added in android 11.

Comment: If this is not supported in android 10. can you please also confirm that is the ') GROUP BY ( _id' hack still supported. Sorry for bothering you as I dont have a test device for android 10.